# Firewall parameter Source:Local Network

Tags: firewall, jelastic

I wanted to know, when parametring a Firewall rule in Jelastic with a source of Local Network, what is exactly meant with **Local Network** ?

Is it :

- All of the node of one environnment ?
- All of the node of all **my** environnments ?
- All of the node of my hoster (would work if I had multiple account or if a colleague server want to connect per LAN to one of my server)

Thanks for the help :)

Would expect it's All of the node of all my environnments